# Highcharts series bars - multiple series, same xAxis

Tags: javascript, highcharts, process, handlebars.js, trace

I am working with Highcharts which represent a mission tracing. The X Axis shows the name of each person and the Y axis is the duration time for each status.

An img for instance:

[image]

I am wondering how can I repeat over a status series on the same X Axis like this:

[image]

Do you have an idea? Please help :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use two or more linked series with the same color and with `[x, y]` data format, for example:

```
    series: [{
        color: 'blue',
        data: [
            [0, 20],
            [1, 6],
            [2, 16]
        ]
    }, {
        data: [
            [0, 20],
            [1, 21],
            [2, 16]
        ]
    }, {
        color: 'blue',
        linkedTo: 0,
        data: [
            [1, 15]
        ]
    }]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hbecsx1p/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bar.linkedTo